# Grails TagLib Get element Value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, grails

I have an own TagLib and one Tag called `boxLink` to generate an Remote Link and open an Modal:

```
Closure boxLink = { attrs, body ->
    Integer modalId = OwnUtil.getRandomNumber(1000)
    Map params = attrs.params ? attrs.params : [:]
    params.put('modalId', modalId)
    Map linkParams =  params


    out << '<a href="#" class="modalBoxLink ' + attrs.class
    if (attrs.title)
        out << ' tooltipSpan" title="' + attrs.title
    out << '" onclick="'
    out << remoteFunction(controller: attrs.controller, action: attrs.action, onLoading: attrs.onClick + ';loadingSpinner()', onComplete: 'removeSpinner()',
            onSuccess: 'viewModalBox(data,' + modalId + ');initForm();', onFailure: 'errorAlert();', params: linkParams)

    out << '">'
    out << body()
    out << '</a>'
}
```

In some Cases I neet to read an value of an Form Element to put it into the data of the AJAX Request, so I tried this

```
if(attrs.elementid){
    def elParam = attrs.elementid
    if(attrs.elementname)
        elParam = attrs.elementname     
    linkParams.put(elParam,"document.getElementById('${attrs.elementid}').value")
 }
```

this generates this data value of the ajax request

```
data:{'modalId': '357','application': 'document.getElementById('elementid').value'}
```

How Can I set an data property of the ajax request by getting the value of an HTML element?

Answer (score 0):

The tag lib is executed on the server, you want the generated code to act on the client. This will only be possible through javascript. You may be best off using jQuery and ajaxForm for this. You could tie a function to the modal opening or some other action and set the value(s) of hidden fields in your form.

Here is an example from what I use, which populates a modal with html from a hidden div and adds data to two hidden fields. Note that I am not using ajaxForm here but it's the same idea.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function configModal() {
    $(".clickable-row").click(function() {
        var row = $(this)
        var modal = $('#notificationModal');
        var title = row.find('td').find('a').html();
        var html = row.find('.notification-content').html();
        var notificationId = row.attr('id');
        modal.find('.modal-body').html( html );
        modal.find('.modal-title').html( title );
        modal.find('#modal-form').find('input[name=id]').attr('value', notificationId)
        modal.find('#modal-form').find('input[name=isDeleted]').attr('checked', row.hasClass('deleted'));
        modal.modal();

        $.post("${createLink(controller: 'notification', action: 'update')}",
                { id : notificationId, isRead : true },
                function() { row.addClass('read'); });
    });
}
$(document).ready(configModal);
</script>
```